# Чтение данных из txt файла

Tags: java, android

Считываю данные txt файла. Проблема в том, что русские символы не читабельны:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1993);
```

В методе `onActivityResult` обрабатываю результат:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) return;
    if (null == data) return;
    //если полученный код равен тому который мы передали
    if (requestCode == 1993) {
        StringBuilder myText = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            String adress = data.getDataString();
            File file = new File(new URI(adress));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            String name = file.getName();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                myText.append(line);
                myText.append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
            textView.setText(myText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните, о каком языке речь. Я мог ошибиться в предположении.

Comment: Считываю на android. язык Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил я данную проблему с помощью класса IOUtils.
В gradle подключаем библиотеку compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
И собственно сам код:

```
 InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"Cp1251");
            String theString = IOUtils.toString(in);
```

Comment: Отметьте ответ как принятый

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так к примеру:

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(br.readLine()), "Cp1251");
    System.out.println(in.getEncoding());
    char show[] = new char[100];
    in.read(show, 0, 100);
    System.out.println(show);
```

С помощью available() можно узнать точный размер txt и использовать, но это уже зависит от того, что вам нужно. Будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
char buf[] = new char[fileIn.available()];
in.read(buf,0,fileIn.available());
System.out.println(buf);
```

Или вот такой вариант:

```
        FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream("FILE_NAME");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInput, "Cp1251"));
        String line = null;
        while ( (line=r.readLine())!=null) {lines.add(line);}
        r.close();
        System.out.println(lines);
```